# Rails production getting 422 error (The change you wanted was rejected)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, digital-ocean

I'm running a Rails production in digital ocean droplet. I can load the static pages, but whenever a controller action (like `create`, `signin`, `signup`) occurs, the server raises a "The change you wanted was rejected." error.
Does anyone know why this happens?

I can add data through console but cannot through the application.

Comment: check production.log of app, and error log your web server (nginx, apache)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have 2 options to solve this.
 1. Set CSRF Token in your cookie
 2. add `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token` in your controller

Comment: In which controller do i have to add `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token`. application_controller??

Comment: In the controller, which returns you this error. You told about actions like `create`. In this controller, you need to add.

Comment: Or you can add this in your base controller (if you have it of course)

Comment: I highly recommend that you DO NOT do `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token`, because wouldn't it expose your application to CSRF attacks?

Comment: You can just put `skip_forgery_protection` at the top of the controller, which does the same thing. And yes there are some totally legitimate reasons for wanting to disable CSRF protection, for example where some of your endpoints are just part of a REST API and are not served as web pages. But it's important to consider the security implications.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it might be due to an external configuration issue e.g in my case everything in rails was fine but in nginx I was missing the `X-Forwarded-Ssl` configuration and was getting

```
HTTP Origin header (https://www.example.com) didn't match 
request.base_url (http://www.example.com)
```

which was solved by setting it up

```
server {
 ....
 location @app {
 ...
   proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
 ...
 }
}
```