# The change you wanted was rejected. Maybe you tried to change something you didn't have access to. in ruby on rails

Tags: android, ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am using ruby on rails and I am add apple signin option its work on firefox but it gives error on
chrome
[error on after login in from apple id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vd0P3.png)

Why this error comes on chrome or when I trying to sign in from android application

**In logs**

```
Parameters: {"state"=>"0fadfb37-5f10-4419-a81b-b37958ce8298", "code"=>"c0417f43c146d49619b0a889c20968ddc.0.srtvv.w1TyBJLB0BW13gicWJCW8g"}
2023-11-28T12:03:01.946455111Z app[web.1]: W, [2023-11-28T12:03:01.946359 #15]  WARN -- : [5b857452-0b97-47a1-8e03-09e9752b16f5] HTTP Origin header (

> https://appleid.apple.com

) didn't match request.base_url 
2023-11-28T12:03:01.946884228Z app[web.1]: I, [2023-11-28T12:03:01.946677 #15]  INFO -- : [5b857452-0b97-47a1-8e03-09e9752b16f5] Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 0ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 280)
2023-11-28T12:03:01.947978352Z app[web.1]: F, [2023-11-28T12:03:01.947828 #15] FATAL -- : [5b857452-0b97-47a1-8e03-09e9752b16f5]   
2023-11-28T12:03:01.948026010Z app[web.1]: [5b857452-0b97-47a1-8e03-09e9752b16f5] ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken):
```

in **application.rb**

```
config.action_dispatch.cookies_same_site_protection = lambda { |request|
  request.path == '/users/auth/apple/callback' ? :none : :lax
}
```

in **omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb**

```
    class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, only: :apple
  
  def google_oauth2
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
  
    if @user.persisted?
      @user.update_after_social_login(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
      flash[:notice] = I18n.t "devise.omniauth_callbacks.success", :kind => "Google"
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
    else
      session["devise.google_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"].except(:extra) #Removing extra as it can overflow some session stores
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url, alert: @user.errors.full_messages.join("\n")
    end
  end



def apple
    @user = User.from_apple_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
    
    if @user.present? && @user.persisted?
      @user.update_after_social_login(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
      flash[:notice] = I18n.t "devise.omniauth_callbacks.success", :kind => "Apple"
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
    else
      session["devise.apple_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"].except(:extra)
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url, alert: @user.errors.full_messages.join("\n")
    end
  end



def facebook
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

    if @user.persisted?
      @user.update_after_social_login(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
    else      
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end

  def failure
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

Comment: can you provide more info or logs printout in your rails server @awais iqbal

Comment: I provide more information in this

Comment: Have you check this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/68464784/17731528 , if this not then try this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/55295484/17731528

Comment: for 1st I  don't that because I am using dokku server and for 2nd its not work for me

Comment: Ok, in your views have you mentioned <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
if you havent then please add this in your erb head tag. please update syntx if using  haml.

Comment: I add this on 
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
<%= csp_meta_tag %> on all html layout but not working